# Get a file base64 from the URI

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

i have been trying to get the base64 of a file. however i could not use the plugin for some reason.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemUrl(path, gotFile, fail);
```

This above code gives me a:

"Property 'resolveLocalFileSystemUrl' does not exist on type 'Window'."

error.

Is there any way to fix it? i have the plugin installed. Also, i have tried(from other stackoverflow answers)

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemUri(path, gotFile, fail);
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, gotFile, fail);
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(path, gotFile, fail);
```

OR if there is another way to retrieve the base64, please assist.

By the way, im using filechoose to open and choose the file.

Comment: 2 things i can think of 
1. wherever u are using the plugin add `declare var window;` on top of it.
2. use that inside platform.ready
`platform.ready().then(() => {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, (dir) => {
    ...
    }
});`

Let me know which option works

Comment: @Lyon, please check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309266/updated-actively-prevent-this-in-title-not-solved-yet and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @OlegEstekhin oops i didnt know about it. thanks for pointing it out!! i have accepted answers from my other posts too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved the issue by re-installing the plugin.

```
getFileContentAsBase64(path, callback){
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, gotFile, fail);

 function fail(e){
   alert('Cannot found requested file');
 }

 function gotFile(fileEntry){
   fileEntry.file(function (file){
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = function(e){
       var content = this.result;
       callback(content);
     }
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   });
 }
}
```

the above code allows you to convert a dataURL(file/image/pdf anything) into base64.

you can call it by:

```
getFileContentAsBase64(obj.toInternalURL().toString(), function (base64File) {
 console.log(base64file);
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anywhere default function name `window.resolveLocalFileSystemUri` it's a `resolveLocalFileSystemURL`

Try Below

```
resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function(entry) {
    var nativePath = entry.toURL();
    console.log('Native URI: ' + nativePath);
    document.getElementById('image').src = nativePath;
});
```

Source is [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)

Make sure you have installed `file-transfer` plugin.